React HTML5 video not running onLoadMetadata and poster not showing
I have this component. But after I upload the video to the server, the <DisplayVideo> component running but inside the video is not loading, and poster not showing. Also, the onLoadedMetadata not running. I even tried setting key with Date.now() to force rerender but no luck. I don't understand the behaviour. It will only work after I manually update something in the component.
const VideoInput = ({ videos, onChange }: Props) => {
  const ref = useRef<any>(null);
  const { dispatch } = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const { seqPartner } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.partner);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState('');

  const selectVideoFile = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target?.files[0]?.size === 0) return null;
    const newInput = e.target?.files[0];
    const maxSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    if (newInput.size > maxSize) {
      alert('only 100mb');
      return null;
    }

    const formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append('videoFile', newInput);
    uploadVideoToServer(formData);
  };

  const uploadVideoToServer = async (formData: FormData) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_START' });
      await api
        .post('/videos/upload', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.status !== 200) {
            alert('server error');
          } else {
            const { data: videoData } = data;

            onChange('videos', [
              {
                id: videoData?.id,
                fileName: videoData?.fileName,
                fileUrl: videoData?.fileUrl,
                videoImgUrl: videoData?.videoImgUrl,
                fileData: formData.get('videoFile'),
              },
            ]);
          }
        });
      dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_END' });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_END' });
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert('deleted');
  };

  const clickVideo = (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (ref?.current) {
      const video = ref?.current;
      var isPlaying =
        video.currentTime > 0 && !video.paused && !video.ended && video.readyState > video.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA;

      if (isPlaying) {
        ref?.current?.pause();
      } else {
        ref?.current?.play();
      }
    }
  };

  const handleLoadedMetadata = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    const video: any = ref.current;
    console.log('metadata', video);

    if (video) {
      const duration = video.duration;
      const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60)
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0');
      const seconds = Math.floor(duration % 60)
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0');
      setDuration(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div style={{ paddingLeft: 64, paddingRight: 24, marginTop: 12 }}>
        {videos?.length > 0 && (
          <DisplayVideo key={videos.length}>
            <div className="video">
              <video
                ref={ref}
                poster={videos[0]?.videoImgUrl}
                preload="metadata"
                onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedMetadata}
                controls={false}
                autoPlay={false}
              >
                <source src={videos[0]?.fileUrl} type="video/mp4" />
              </video>

              <div className="deleteButtonContainer">
                <img src={DeleteIcon} alt="" onClick={handleDelete} />
              </div>

              <div className="darkOverlay">
                <div className="playButton" onClick={clickVideo}>
                  <img src={VideoPlayButton} alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>

              {!!duration.length && <div className="duration">{duration}</div>}
            </div>
          </DisplayVideo>
        )}

        <Label disabled={videos?.length > 0}>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="video/mp4,video/mkv, video/x-m4v,video/*"
            disabled={videos.length > 0}
            onInput={selectVideoFile}
          />
          <img src={VideoUploadIcon} alt="" />
         upload video
          <span style={{ minWidth: '6px' }}></span>
        </Label>
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

Tried everything with useEffect and other things
